# Does a bias resistor determine the forward voltage drop across an LED?

Tags: led

I hadn't really given this much though before but when I look at the forward voltage drop of a LED, it gives a graph such [as](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1498852.pdf)

[image]

[image]

Can I simply set the resistor to a value produce a current and get the corresponding forward voltage drop or is there an associated resistor within the LED for which I need to account?

Comment: Can you explain how/why the effect of the "associated resistor within the LED" is **not** visible from the If/Vf plot you show? Think about this: suppose there is this *associated resistor within the LED*, how would you measure the LED without talking into account the influence of that resistor?

Comment: Thanks @ElliotAlderson (great name). So basically Ron in led doesn't matter?  Curious as it was very important in a h bridge transistor I did recently.

Comment: There is no "Ron" for a diode. You could talk about the instantaneous **slope** of the I/V curve as a kind of equivalent conductance, but it is a gross oversimplification of how a diode behaves.

Comment: If you are looking for a graphical/intuitive way to understand, take a look at [this great answer from user Transistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/346806/2677).

Answer (score 1):

If you want 5mA then there is 2.0V over the LED, and you can calculate resistance based on the current and voltage that is over the resistor. If you want 20mA then same applies but there just is 2.2V over LED so there is less voltage over the resistor.

So basically yes, bias resistor determines forward voltage. By changing the resistor, current changes, which also changes forward voltage over LED.